# node.js send data to client?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I wonder how can I send data from node.js to client?

example node.js code -

```
var http = require('http');

var data = "data to send to client";

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("Hello World\n");
}).listen(8125);
```

Now, I want to send the `data` variable to client and log it with JavaScript..

 How can I do that?

Thanks ;)

**EDIT:** Does anyone know how to send array?

Comment: Basicly i would choose for sockets. Like [socket.io](http://socket.io/). That way you can communicate via the socket from client to server and from server to client. Common used for realtime chat applications

Answer (score 6):

If You Want to do it after `response.end` you should use [Socket.io](http://socket.io) or Server Send Events.

If you want it before `res.end`, you would make your code look like:

```
var http = require('http');

var data = "data to send to client";

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write(data); // You Can Call Response.write Infinite Times BEFORE response.end
    response.end("Hello World\n");
}).listen(8125);
```

Comment: Can you read what I wrote please, and tell me what you didn't understand from that?

Comment: Where did you find `response.write`? There is no any `response.write` method http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res

Comment: Ok, I get it https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback